# "Rescue dog" meaning

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm a little bit confused of the word *rescue* usage. From one perspective of view I know from the grounds about the television series "Chip'n Dale: Rescue Rangers" in which Rangers are rescuing others. On the other hand, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_dog) says that "A rescue dog is a dog that is rescued from a possible euthanasia" - the opposite meaning.

So the question is - does the word *rescue* have these opposite meanings? And how can I refer to "A dog designated for rescue missions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Wikipedia article which you drew that definition from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_dog) says (right under the title):

> *Not to be confused with [Search and rescue dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_and_rescue_dog).*

From that article:

> The use of dogs in search and rescue (SAR) is a valuable component in wilderness tracking, natural disasters, mass casualty events, and in locating missing people. Dedicated handlers and well-trained dogs are required for the use of dogs to be effective in search efforts. Search and rescue dogs are typically worked, by a small team on foot.
>
> Search and rescue dogs detect human scent. Although the exact processes are still researched, it may include skin rafts (scent-carrying skin cells that drop off living humans at a rate of about 40,000 cells per minute), evaporated perspiration, respiratory gases, or decomposition gases released by bacterial action on human skin or tissues.

So a **search and rescue dog** is the term you're looking for. On the same web page you'll find that these SAR dogs are also further classified according to specific criteria.